# JS doesn't work after using magento setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2

I'm completely new to a Magento 2 and I'm facing a problem.

Somewhy, after using `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command, my admin panel doesn't work properly. Styles are not loaded correctly and I cannot browse through the panel (none of the selections appears).

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` command solves that at that moment, but after using `setup:upgrade`, it happens again and I don't want to use deploy command every time after I'm using upgrade. It takes a lot of time to complete deploy and it's a waste of it.

Tried to change `Symlink` to `Copy` in di.xml file, but it didn't helped.

Any suggestions? Thanks for any help.

Comment: enable developer mode?

Comment: I'm using the developer mode

Comment: Set the permissions correctly to var, pub/static, generated

Comment: @SukumarGorai could you evaluate on how to do that?

Comment: After running setup:upgrade, set chmod 777 -R var/ pub/static/ generated. Then run static content deploy and set the permissions again.

Comment: @SukumarGorai do you mean "pub/static", not "var/pub/static/"? Because var/pub/static doesn't exist.

Comment: I mean var and pub/static and generated. Total 3 folders

Comment: here you can see deploy command option:https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html

With --theme option you can deploy to specific theme that can reduce your time of deploy.

Comment: @SukumarGorai your solution didn't worked. :(